# Change Facebook profile pic

Tags: facebook, profile

I'm trying to figure out if this is allowed (calling this from my app):

```
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=[PID]&set=[PIC]&type=1&makeprofile=1
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible using API

Comment: I know its not possible with the api. But in any case i can still call this. Just trying to get around if its allowed. Thanks

Comment: @Ian Benschop: it violates FB TOS, thus it is illegal. I wouldn't do that

Comment: Thanks, I looked and read it many time. It's always a abstract thing but I geuss it would infringe with 1.1 You must not circumvent (or claim to circumvent) our intended limitations on core Facebook features and functionality. Be awesome if I could chat with someone from facebook directly.

Comment: If you're redirecting your app's user to that URL, it might work (but i wouldn't rely on it working in case the URL structure or parameters change) - but it's probably better to just link the user to the photo and let them use the 'Make this my profile picture' feature directly